# Find keywords used to get to page on Google analytics

Tags: google-analytics

In GA is there a simple way to find out what keywords were used to get to a page?

I am looking at my IIS logs and it seems this is the first page users from Google search results hit. Would be great to know the keywords they searched for on Google.

Answer (score 1):

You won't see most of the keywords in your IIS logs any more.  Google stopped sending keywords in the referrer field 90% of the time.   Google Analytics used to have a great report for search engine keywords, but without the data from Google Search, it isn't much use.   You can still get to it, but you will find that 90% of your search engine referrer keywords are "not provided".   The report can still be accessed under the path: **Acquisition** -> **All Traffic** -> **Channels** -> **Organic Search**.

You can get the keywords for which your webpage is ranking by logging into Google Search Console and viewing the [Search Analytics Report](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/6155685?hl=en).  That report will tell you:

- What keywords your site in the rankings for
- What your average ranking position is
- How many clicks you got for each keyword
- What pages show up in the results for each keyword

You can [associate your Search Console data with your Google Analytics data](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/1120006?hl=en) which will allow you to see the search console search analytics directly in Google Analytics.

Answer (score 0):

What you looking for is this: **Acquisition > Search Console > Queries**

In order to have an access to this, you need to connect your Search Console and GA accounts.